# PHP date formatting - Can I use 'Sept' instead of 'Sep'?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a site with date formatting but I want to use Sept instead of Sep for September, is this possible?

Comment: Use the full month name and `substr`

Comment: do you want specifically for september?

Comment: No. Not without string manipulation.

Comment: str_replace() does the job. Think a bit before posting question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not right out of the box but just replace `Sep` with `Sept`

```
$month = str_replace('Sep', 'Sept', date('M'));
```

Comment: @Dale, You would want to do this because according to the Associated Press, [http://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/abbreviations/](Oxford English Dictionary) and other authorities, the abbreviation for September is Sept. not Sep. I give @MrCode +1 because his code works for other months too, since all other months are abbreviated with three letters. As Dale says, `substr` will give you weird results for any other month.

Comment: The [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) says that the strtotime(), DateTime and date_create() parser understands both 'sep' and 'sept' but only three letter dates are valid for the [`date`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example

```
echo substr(date('F'), 0, 4);
```

You're going to get weird results with 'January' though.

Not sure why you want to do this

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the required output

```
<?php
 $month = date('F');
 $month_name =  substr($month,0,4);
 echo $month_name;
?>
```